# Problem with rename and mask the point

Tags: perl, rename, regex

Lets assume that I want to rename a file:

"topography_9x9._001.png"   to "topography_9x9_001.png"

I would use

```
 rename -n s/9\./9/g
 topography_9x9._001.png renamed as topography_99_001.png
```

Why is the point not masked by the backslash?

Answer (score 4):

You didn't quote the regex, so `\` was interpreted by the shell:

```
$ echo  rename -n s/9\./9/g
rename -n s/9./9/g
```

Quote your regexes:

```
rename -n 's/9\./9/g'
```

Comment: I wonder why I did not fell earlier over this mistake. 
In this special case double masking would work as well: 
rename -n s/9\\./9/g *
Although I see that I must regularly quote in the future.